# Acepen graphics tablet with Tecno Pop 8 phone; synchronises well, but no cursor displayed

Tags: customization, user-interface

Tecno Pop 8 phone with Acepen graphics tablet.
No cursor displayed on screen.
Drawing with an invisible pen tip can be a bit frustrating.

How can I get the cursor to display?